# How to dynamically resize text size in a UITextView on iPhone 4S Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

My app shows a string array that iterates through by button press. It works perfectly on all devices except iPhone 4S. The problem is some string elements are to long to fit within the UITextView and you have to scroll to read the rest of it, which I do not want.

So, my question is how to dynamically shrink attributed text to fit within a constrained UITextView when it doesn't fit all the string element?

Let me know if this is possible,
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `UITextView`, when you can use `UILabel` for you situation. `UITextView` does not have autoscaling property. With `UILabel` you can set number of lines and it has `Autoshrink`property where you can set `Minimum font scale` or `Minimum font size` that will adjust your text accordingly to `UILabel` size. Or just allow scrolling with `UITextView`.

Comment: These would've saved me so much time. Thanks!

Comment: This still misses the point of the question, there are many valid reasons to use a `UITextView` over `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your textview category class to fit font size depend upon width.

```
-(BOOL)sizeFontToFit:(NSString*)aString minSize:(float)aMinFontSize maxSize:(float)aMaxFontSize 
{   
float fudgeFactor = 16.0;
float fontSize = aMaxFontSize;

self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize];

CGSize tallerSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width-fudgeFactor,kMaxFieldHeight);
CGSize stringSize = [aString sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

while (stringSize.height >= self.frame.size.height)
       {
       if (fontSize <= aMinFontSize) // it just won't fit
           return NO;

       fontSize -= 1.0;
       self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize];
       tallerSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width-fudgeFactor,kMaxFieldHeight);
       stringSize = [aString sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
       }

return YES; 
}
```