How to dynamically adjust font size in the UITextView (Xcode 16)?
I am having trouble with adjusting text font size inside UITextView using Swift and Xcode so that when somebody is using smaller screen (like iPhone SE 3), the text is smaller and should fit the view nicely without the need for scrolling (that is my workaround for now). For bigger screens, the drawback is that there is a lot of empty space and ideally the text should be bigger here so that it occupies the view more elegantly. I checked the forum, but many of the solutions are old and not applicable. I think I should use TextView for general displaying bigger text chunks instead of UILabel. See screenshots and here is my ViewController code:
        // consent text view
        consentTextView.backgroundColor = .systemGray5
        consentTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        consentTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
        consentTextView.isEditable = false
        
        let consentAlign = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        consentAlign.alignment = .justified
                
        let consentAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 15.0)!,
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: consentAlign,
        ]
        
        // consent text
        let contentString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:
            "The content of the app is intended for healthcare professionals only. The information contained within the app is not intended for the general public." +
            "\n" +
            "\nI confirm that I am a professional within the meaning of §2a of Act No. 40/1995 Coll., on advertising regulation, as amended, i.e., a person authorized to prescribe medicinal products or a person authorized to dispense medicinal products." +
            "\n" +
            "\nI acknowledge that the information contained herein is not intended for the general public, but for healthcare professionals, with all the risks and consequences arising therefrom for the general public." +
            "\n" +
            "\nAfter confirmation, you can continue using the app. We appreciate your understanding - enjoy NeoTools!"
            ,attributes: consentAttributes
        )
        
        // consent text specific attributes
        contentString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 15.0)!, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 68))
        contentString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.handbookBlue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 68))
        
        contentString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 15.0)!, range: NSRange(location: 597, length: 102))
        contentString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.handbookBlue, range: NSRange(location: 597, length: 102))

        // consent text append
        consentTextView.attributedText = contentString



Thank you very much for any help!
I checked the forum, but many of the solutions are old and not applicable. I think I should use TextView for general displaying bigger text chunks instead of UILabel.
I tried things like Automatically adjusts font, compare content height to view height, adjust to fit, scaling options, scaling based on the device, et cetera.
I found something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550192/how-to-dynamically-resize-text-size-in-a-uitextview-on-iphone-4s-swift, however, it revolves around the same thing - should I just use UILabel or stick with the scrolling?

This doesn't answer your question, but these links provide some guidance to consider about Dynamic Type.
HIG: accessibility
HIG: typography
Dynamic Type
There may be something to work through with respect to using NSAttributedString with Dynamic Type.

I added a comment on this question with some links to resources about Dynamic Type. I replicated your UI using that approach in the following gist so you can see what that might look like. Gist
You may want to implement different UI, or differences in your existing UI, based on the size class of the user's device. Ensuring things look right on the various devices is a big part of the UI side of app development.
You may want to consider fetching the consent agreement's text from a service as simplified HTML. If you do that, you can create an NSAttributedString using the HTML. The HTML can style the text as blue, and I think you can still set the font using Dynamic Type approach from the gist (I didn't verify this). If you're fetching HTML for the consent agreement, you'll be able to change the text without recompiling your app.
